# EPub reader XML?

Tags: epub

I have a doubt in this. If i have OEBPS instead of OPS. How can i parse it? Please help me in this.

```
<container xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container" version="1.0">
  <rootfiles>
    <rootfile full-path="OEBPS/content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
  </rootfiles>
</container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the path name not the early incarnation of the EPUB specifications (the name OEBPS comes from Open Ebook Publications Specification iirc).

In which case, the `full-path` attribute simply tells your reading software where to go and find the package file. What's the problem? It's just a different directory. You should be using the attribute to find the file anyway.